# Websphere : Where should I add the jar file for LoginModule

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8, ibm-was

I have written a login module in WebSphere, if I want to use it in application level I can add that in shared libraries, but right now I want to use it under system login under the RMI_Inbound, I can add the path of my class there, but where exactly I need to put the jar files and how to configure it ?

I have gone through many documents but none tells where to keep jar file or edit any xml, they all tell just to mention the classname of loginmodule like com.custom.loginmodule .

Comment: If you want to add it in the RMI_Inbound, then the best place would be `WebSphere\AppServer\lib\ext` folder.

Comment: Thanks , I will try putting it there

Comment: Remember that you have to restart the server to make it visible in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add it in the `RMI_Inbound`, then the best place would be `WebSphere\AppServer\lib\ext` folder. After adding jar you have to restart the server to make classes visible in the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Configuring programmatic logins for Java Authentication and Authorization Service](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_j2clogin.html) topic in the Knowledge Center:

> Proxy LoginModule. The Proxy LoginModule loads the actual LoginModule
>   module. The default JAAS implementation does not use the thread
>   context class loader to load classes. The LoginModule module cannot
>   load if the LoginModule class file is not in the application class
>   loader or the Java extension class loader class path. Due to this
>   class loader visibility problem, WebSphere Application Server provides
>   a proxy LoginModule module to load the JAAS LoginModule using the
>   thread context class loader. You do not need to place the LoginModule
>   implementation on the application class loader or the class path for
>   the Java extension class loader with this proxy LoginModule module.
>
> If you do not want to use the Proxy LoginModule module, you can place the LoginModule module in the app_server_root/lib/ext/ directory. **However, this action is not recommended due to the security risks.**

I would configure a server-associated shared library.  See the [Associating shared libraries with servers](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tcws_sharedlib_server.html) topic in the Knowledge Center.

Comment: So what kind of security risk it can bring, and how that security risk is mitigated by using shared library? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Gas I don't know for sure, but I might guess Java 2 security; it might be reasonable to ask IBM for more details on that sentence.  Shared library is probably a bit cleaner in any case since it doesn't require modifying the installation directory.

Comment: thanks for the information, I was in doubt that shared library can only be used in application level and not at system level ?

Comment: @Friendy shared library can be used at server level, you do it via classloader. Check [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib_server.html?lang=en) for more details.